# Can I update a document base on collection condition?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I would Like to make sure some ***condition*** is met before performing an ***update*** operation.

Is this possible with MongoDB in a single query?

For example, I have the following collection A:

```json
{"_id":"1", "content":{"a":1, "b":2}},
{"_id":"2", "content":{"a":1, "b":2}},
```

I would like to perform an update on a document where "_id" is "1", only if there is no document that has "_id":"2" in this entire collection A.

Comment: well for sure I can do a find first and proceed if nothing comes out. Wonder something like the aggregate can skip that check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `$lookup` to check for the existence of doc `_id:"2"`. After that, based on the `$lookup` result to perform `$merge` to update back to doc `_id:"1"`.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      _id: "1"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "collection",
      "let": {
        docId: "2"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$_id",
                "$$docId"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "doc2"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      doc2: []
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      someNewFields: "..."
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      doc2: false
    }
  },
  {
    "$merge": {
      "into": "collection",
      "on": "_id",
      "whenMatched": "replace"
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/md4umyW7xiI) that doc `_id:"2"` exists.

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/y2WsPRQ3dqf) that doc `_id:"2"` does not exist.

Comment: oh wow, $merge actually did the trick. 

Only problem with this is that we end up with an unwanted "doc2":[] merged into target document

Comment: @idler1515 sorry my bad. Updated the solution to sanitize the doc2 field using `$project`

Comment: Solved my problem, thx bro! Wondering about the consumption of running such a pipeline, is there any docs that describe how the pipeline runs from mongo by any chances?

Comment: @idler1515 it depends on what you mean by "consumption". You could be looking for [`explain()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/)